# Developing for IPhone 4s, 5, 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, iphone-6

I've been working on a specific app for a while now and everything was good. But upon all this news of the iPhone 6 and the new Xcode, everything has just become confusing. Using Auto layout and designing for the iPhone have just become the most complicated thing to do. Every time I add constraints my images just triple in size. When all I want is to resize them to fit rationally across all the iPhone platforms(In portrait mode). For example I would like for certain images to grow as I work From the iPhone 5 to the 6+. Does any one know how to do this?

Comment: Try by unchecking "Constrain to margins" checkbox while adding constraints (in new XCode) and everything should work fine.

Comment: @Bhumit It's still the same deal. Is it possible for me to just recreate each one separately using multiply storyboard?

Comment: I would definatly not recommend to use multiple storyboard for this purpose, as whole autolayout thing is for adjusting multiple screen size devices within single storyboard.

Comment: I understand but I feel like it may be the easiest thing for me to do right now. Because with the iPhone 6 and Xcode 6 being  so new I just can't seem to find the information I need. So I just want to know if it is possible and if so how?

Comment: @Bhumit sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink . Have a look at this project, i havent really used it or gone in details , but this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean triple in size?

Easiest way to have an image view scale is do the following:

- Add it as a subview to the view of your view controller
- Pin it at the top, left and right, leaving height unconstrained
- Add an aspect ratio constraint, so that it can automatically calculate its height based on the width it gets

Comment: "Add an aspect ratio constraint" ..how the hell? lol first time I heard about this. Please provide sample code. :D

Comment: What a waste of time. Anyway: CGFloat ratio = 1.0;
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:myView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:myView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
    multiplier:ratio
    constant:0];
constraint.priority = 1000;
[myView.superview addConstraint:constraint];